# How can I start a java program by sending an email

Tags: java, jenkins

We are working on a project and Im involved in continuous integration testing.

I need to

- deploy the new project code on a staging server, not using Jenkins, but ftp;
- after the deploy an email is sent to indicate successfull deploy and we need it to start my integration tests;
- integration tests, if successfull, will start a deploy on integration server.

I am going to write a java program that will login to Jenkins and execute the integration tests.

Question is: how can the email message activate the java program?

EDIT: Normally, jenkins offers a feature that starts a job after getting an email, but we are having a security problem with that

Comment: This seems like a very complicated approach. I'm guessing your Jenkins does the deployment to the staging server? If so, why don't just start the next Jenkins job after that one is done?

Comment: no, staging server deploy is done via ftp...

Comment: You could make that a jenkins job too. Jenkins can do a lot of various things during a job, including publishing files to FTP. I think you will have a lot less work if you get your build process straight instead of writing the workaround you intend to.

Comment: well the initial deploy is done by our developer and he is very busy, and is working from distance so I dont want to bother him

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You are adding complexity via email and keep manual operations instead of automating the FTP deployment. Use jenkins to do the FTP deployment. You won't depend on your 'busy' developer anymore. Keep him busy with development, not manual operations. Move the FTP deployment task to jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a program or script which will peridically poll a mail server box and upon getting an appropirate email will run another java program.

Comment: More generally, many scripting languages also have the features needed to poll a mailbox and start a Java program.

Comment: may I do that not using a browser? I might write a selenium "test" that will open the email and look for new mail, but is there a way that I do that without ever opening a browser? Sorry im new to Java (6 weeks) and I am not very confident

Answer (score 2):

Please read Jenkins documentation thoroughly. If you are using a version control system, Jenkins can automatically pull the code and run test cases on it. You can notify Jenkins using various methods... including webhooks.

Do go through various [plugins for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins).

**Update**:

I have not used this myself. But looks like this is what you want: [Mail Commander Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Commander+Plugin)

And the command you send can be something like this:

```
curl --data '' http://<server>:<port>/job/<projectname>/build
```

Comment: yeah, we have some problems with this jenkins feature, so Im trying to work around it